# mysql sometimes removes and old index when adding a new index?

Tags: mysql

## TL;DR

We've seen on a virtual machine, that adding a UNIQUE index causes an older non-UNIQUE index to be removed automatically.

I cannot reproduce this on any other machines (yet?), and if I do:

```
mysql -e 'create db2'
mysqldump db1 | mysql db2
```

before adding the new index to db1, and then try adding the index on db2 instead, the old index is *not* removed from db2. Funky!

We have a snapshot of the machine with db1, and can reproduce it there in the existing db1 database...

Anybody have any idea what is going on? We have scripts to automate adding/removing indexes, and that started failing because on that one machine, the old index didn't exist any longer.

When a dump/restore cycle causes the problem to go away, that makes it hard understand, reproduce and reduce the problem to a simple example.

## Details

The table in question looked like this before adding the new index (from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`). Note the `monitoredTableRowID` KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE `cfgAttributeInstances` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attributeID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `statisticID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeStatisticID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `serviceID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeServiceID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeComponentID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `syslogFilterID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeID` (`nodeID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `groupID` (`groupID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `statisticID` (`statisticID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeStatisticID` (`nodeStatisticID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serviceID` (`serviceID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeServiceID` (`nodeServiceID`,`attributeID`),
  KEY `attributeID` (`attributeID`),
  KEY `monitoredTableRowID` (`nodeComponentID`),
  KEY `syslogFilterID` (`syslogFilterID`),
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attributeID`) REFERENCES `cfgAttributes` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodes` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`groupID`) REFERENCES `cfgGroups` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`statisticID`) REFERENCES `cfgStatistics` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeStatisticID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodeStatistics` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`serviceID`) REFERENCES `cfgServices` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeServiceID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodeServices` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeComponentID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodeComponents` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`syslogFilterID`) REFERENCES `cfgSyslogFilters` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='CapMon Attribute instances';
```

I added this index:

```
ALTER TABLE cfgAttributeInstances ADD
    UNIQUE new_nodeComponentID (nodeComponentID, attributeID)
```

It looked like this after adding that index:

```
CREATE TABLE `cfgAttributeInstances` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attributeID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `statisticID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeStatisticID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `serviceID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeServiceID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodeComponentID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `syslogFilterID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeID` (`nodeID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `groupID` (`groupID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `statisticID` (`statisticID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeStatisticID` (`nodeStatisticID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serviceID` (`serviceID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeServiceID` (`nodeServiceID`,`attributeID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `new_nodeComponentID` (`nodeComponentID`,`attributeID`),
  KEY `attributeID` (`attributeID`),
  KEY `syslogFilterID` (`syslogFilterID`),
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attributeID`) REFERENCES `cfgAttributes` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodes` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`groupID`) REFERENCES `cfgGroups` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`statisticID`) REFERENCES `cfgStatistics` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeStatisticID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodeStatistics` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`serviceID`) REFERENCES `cfgServices` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeServiceID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodeServices` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`nodeComponentID`) REFERENCES `cfgNodeComponents` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cfgAttributeInstances_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`syslogFilterID`) REFERENCES `cfgSyslogFilters` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='CapMon Attribute instances';
```

But hey! Where did the `monitoredTableRowID` index go?

Again, I cannot reproduce this. If I do a `mysqldump > dump.db`/`mysql < dump.db` cycle, the `monitoredTableRowID` doesn't disappear...

Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composite key with `nodeComponentID` causes the non-composite key with `nodeComponentID` to be redundant within the context of the foreign key reference it is used. MySQL automatically drops the redundant implicit index. The behavior is dependant on column index ordering, as the dropped index will always be the first column within the defined composite key. [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html#innodb-foreign-key-definitions)

The issue(s) are specifically caused by the automatic implicit index created when adding a foreign key `CONSTRAINT`, and the index(es) being explicitly defined in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` which is also used by `mysqldump`.

> The **`index_name` value is ignored if there is already an explicitly
>   defined index** on the child table that can support the foreign key.
>   Otherwise, MySQL **implicitly creates a foreign key index**...  [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   **index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.**
>   `index_name`, if given, is used as described previously. [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

To reproduce the issue

### Implicit Key Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sqyPJt46mT7HGzmAZhDoCT/0)

*Note - `INDEX FK_BAR_FOO (foo_id)` is not explicitly defined.*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BAR`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FOO`;

CREATE TABLE `FOO` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `BAR` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `foo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_BAR_FOO` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `FOO` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

SHOW CREATE TABLE `BAR`;
```

**Result**

`INDEX FK_BAR_FOO (foo_id)` is explicitly defined in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but is implicitly created by MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `BAR` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `foo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_BAR_FOO` (`foo_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_BAR_FOO` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `FOO` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

### Composite Key Example: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/daTyWfkcwfHgJsobSxxQDN/0)

```
ALTER TABLE `BAR`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `foo_id_b` (`foo_id`, `b`);

SHOW CREATE TABLE `BAR`;
```

**Result**

`foo_id` index is removed due to being redundant.
Since `foo_id` is the first column within the composite key, the *implicit* `foo_id` index `FK_BAR_FOO` is removed.

```
CREATE TABLE `BAR` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `foo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `foo_id_b` (`foo_id`, `b`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_BAR_FOO` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `FOO` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

### Explicit Key Example: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vWMBdEVcGANUnfDSwoELtF/0)

MySQL ignores the redundant indexes, if the table was created with an *explicit* index that satisfies the foreign key `CONSTRAINT`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BAR`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FOO`;

CREATE TABLE `FOO` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `BAR` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `foo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_BAR_FOO` (`foo_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_BAR_FOO` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `FOO` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

ALTER TABLE `BAR`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `foo_id_b` (`foo_id`, `b`);

SHOW CREATE TABLE `BAR`;
```

**Result**

Composite-key index for `foo_id, b` and index on `foo_id` are created.

```
CREATE TABLE `BAR` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `foo_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `b` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `foo_id_b` (`foo_id`, `b`),
    INDEX `FK_BAR_FOO` (`foo_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_BAR_FOO` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `FOO` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

---

### Solution

In your scripts, verify the index (does not) exist before attempting to drop/add the index.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS  
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'cfgAttributeInstances'
    AND INDEX_NAME = 'new_nodeComponentID' 
    AND INDEX_SCHEMA = 'DbName') 
THEN
    ALTER TABLE `cfgAttributeInstances`
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `new_nodeComponentID` (`nodeComponentID`,`attributeID`);
END IF;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS  
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'cfgAttributeInstances'
    AND INDEX_NAME = 'nodeComponentID' 
    AND INDEX_SCHEMA = 'DbName') 
THEN
   ALTER TABLE `cfgAttributeInstances` 
   DROP INDEX `nodeComponentID`;
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I don't understand is: Why isn't this reproducible for us after a `mysqldump` / restore cycle? Why do db1 and db2 from the original question behave differently?

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch as for why db1 and db2 work differently, it is because the table schema was probably dumped to one of the servers as in my second example. Issuing the queries in the order I did in the first example, will perform the same on both of your db1 and db2 servers, as it does on db-fiddle. Unless they are different mysql versions that does not support redundant index dropping.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch found the documentation reference and updated with link and quote.